# is it possible to change the CollectionViewFlowLayout to CollectionViewLayout in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

is it possible to change the CollectionViewFlowLayout to CollectionViewLayout in storyboard,because i need to implement the water flow or Pinterest Layout,in examples
[RFQuiltLayout](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout),
[BDDynamicGridViewController](https://github.com/norsez/BDDynamicGridViewController)
 they written in collectionViewLayout only,in the storyboard not take this one it list only the collectionViewLayout,so it possible or not,otherwise i follow the collectionviewlayout in programatically?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer to change the CollectionViewFlowLayout to CollectionViewLayout in storyboard.
swift to identify to attribute inspector,in that under the collectionView in layout you can change the flow to custom.now you use the UIViewLayout in Stroyboard like this

[image: Attribute Inspector]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the class in the Identity inspector:

[image: Identity inspector with set class]

In this case, the Class dropdown will show all the classes in your project which are subclasses of `UICollectionViewLayout`. The only implementation which Apple ships is `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, which is a powerful option, and worth considering subclassing before you create your own layout.